# Business application - framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm writing a business application using Entity Framework and there are some things that I need like:

- transaction and transaction scope management **
- data filtering
- control over refreshing data from the db (eg. every 15 s)
- be able to manage what changes are being made to the data and to be able to undo some of them

Those things aren't supported in any way by Entity Framework (or at least it's not easy to accomplish it).

Are there any libraries that sit on top of EF and can do that (or maybe they have their own ORMs) ?
Do I really have to implement that myself?

** I mean something like: I have an object and want to do some changes to it  - I start a transaction and every change that is done from that point in time is included in the transaction, then I commit and that's all that gets commited to the db - other objects live their own happy lives.

Comment: What do you find hard about any of the things you mentioned in Entity framework? Not only are all of those things available without any external libraries, they are all very easy to accomplish. A quick search on "entity framework transaction" provides a ton of examples.

Comment: Implementing any of these features alone is very easy, but if you want to combine all of these things it's becoming more and more complex. Then multiply this by the factor of eg. 100 in a small business app and you end up with a looot of repeated work because "it's easy".

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't any standard ORM do all that for you? Both Hibernate and SQLAlchemy (the big ones I've worked with so far) will do all that stuff for you. They both support transactions, versioning, filtering is straightforward and both support rollbacks during transactions.

For rapid business application development, have a look at Spring Roo, Entity Framework sounds like something that is not ready for the market, Spring is.

Quote from wikipedia: The first version of Entity Framework (EFv1) was included with .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 and Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1, released on 11 August 2008. This version has been widely criticized, even attracting a 'vote of no confidence' signed by several hundred developers.

Comment: I'm using EFv4 (second version published with .NET 4.0) which is greatly improved, but still lacks many features. I'll certainly look at Spring Roo. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Spring Roo is only available for Java - am I right? I've found one forum topic about porting it to .net, but I don't think it has happened yet.

Comment: Yes, that is true, Spring Roo is only for Java, I used to run away from Java as far as possible until I found Spring Roo, now I pump out business applications overnight.
Once I have the databaes schema designed on paper, it takes me 20 minutes to create pretty much most of the backend, have the ORM generated for me and then most of the time is spent building the UI after which I slap in the security layer (which is also provided with Spring Security) and voila, you have a complete business application in a week or two.

Comment: The thing that keeps me far from java is mostly the UI.. I know java has to offer much more then .net in many areas, but creating the UI with swing, well..

Comment: Swing is nightmare indeed, why not opt for a web based application?
There's always GWT, with Spring Roo you just type GWT setup and GWT is fully integrated into your project, then your application turns into a full AJAX / WEB2.0 application that will give your web application the feel of a desktop application.
The alternatives is JSF, Apache Tiles (which comes bundled with Spring Roo), Tapestry and the list goes on.
Mixing in some jQuery or ExtJS can also be done if you don't want to go the GWT route, standard Spring Roo generated interface comes bundled wiht Dojo.

Comment: Also have a look at the Flex addon for Roo.